# Integrate bash test scripts in cmake

Tags: c++, bash, cmake

I have a C++ cmake project that uses Boost Test for unit testing. Now I would like to expose a series of bash scripts (used for integration testing) to cmake. Suppose each of this script to return 0 in case of **PASS** or something != 0 in case of **FAILURE**. I would like each script to be executed whenever I run `cmake test`.

What's the simplest and quickest way to obtain such behavior

Comment: Note that `bash` is unix-specific tool, if you want to be cross-platformic you need to use something like python or cmake inself (see [cmake -E](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html))

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have any reference to some recipes for using cmake command mode for writing test cases?

Comment: Nope, not any specials. Just use it as a usual script and you know... sanity :) Example of [project](http://pastebin.com/1EYj0ARV) and [testing script](http://pastebin.com/FRvnQcX0).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, you want to start by locating the bash program

```
find_program (BASH_PROGRAM bash)
```

Then just add your script to the list of tests

```
if (BASH_PROGRAM)
  add_test (mytest ${BASH_PROGRAM} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh)
endif (BASH_PROGRAM)
```

And all of that should work.