# How to use redirection in cmake add_test

Tags: cmake, makefile, integration-testing

I have a console application called "foo", which takes a reference text file as input (in.txt) and generates text at standard output (I want to keep this behaviour).

In make (not cmake), I use a test target, which calls foo and redirects the output to a file (out.txt) as follows. Then, I use diff to compare the file out.txt with the expected refernece (ref.txt)

```
test:
    ./foo -a test/in.txt > test/out.txt
    diff test/out.txt test/ref.txt
```

This works fine using make. Now my question is; *how can I use cmake to create a similar Makefile?*

From within a subdrectory called build, I tried

```
project(foo)
...
add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND ./foo ../test/in.txt > ../test/out.txt)
enable_testing()
```

Using cmake version 3.5, I get a Makefile without errors, but when I call `make test`, the test itself fails. It seems the cmake command `add_test` supports command line arguments, but not the redirection. I tried quotes and escaping witout success. Since I could not pass this part, I didn't try to use diff. I just imagine that I could pack foo and diff in one line using & as you can do with bash. That would be the second step.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

As @Tsyvarev has stated, CTest commands are not run in a shell's context. But you could just add the shell needed yourself and use e.g. `sh` as the command to be called with `add_test()`.

I've run some tests with your example code and the following did work successfully:

```
add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND sh -c "$<TARGET_FILE:foo> ../test/in.txt > ../test/out.txt")
```

This solution is not platform independent (it depends on `sh` to be available in the search paths).

---

So if you want to be more flexible you could do something like:

```
include(FindUnixCommands)

file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/in.txt" _in)
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/out.txt" _out)
if (BASH)
    add_test(
        NAME test1 
        COMMAND ${BASH} -c "$<TARGET_FILE:foo> ${_in} > ${_out}"
    )
else()
    if (WIN32)
        add_test(
            NAME test1 
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo> $ENV{ComSpec} /c "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:foo> ${_in} > ${_out}"
        )
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown shell command for ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME}")
    endif()
endif()
```

---

Additionally there is the possibility to execute a more platform independent `diff` with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files <file1> <file2>`. So you could simplify your complete makefile based example in CMake with:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET foo
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Running $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:foo> ..."
    COMMAND foo in.txt > out.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test
)

add_test(
    NAME test1 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files in.txt out.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test
)
```

**References**

- [Integrate bash test scripts in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627336/integrate-bash-test-scripts-in-cmake)
- [CMake: piping commands to executable](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044502.html)
- [cmake: make tests successfully passing part of the build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697186/cmake-make-tests-successfully-passing-part-of-the-build-process)

Answer (score 2):

[They say](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-July/038482.html) you cannot:

> There is no redirection of output using add_test arguments.

Unlike to commands in `add_custom_command`, which are executed as a part of makefile receipts (that is, in the context of some *shell*), tests are executed directly by CTest, **without any shell involved**. So, shell mechanisms don't work for tests.

You may create wrapper script, which calls program, given as parameter, and performs redirection, futher `diff` and so on. Then use this script (with appropriate arguments) as a `COMMAND` for `add_test`.

Comment: After seeing [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044502.html) post, I thought one solution to embed the script into CMake could be - if the point is not platform independence - to just add the shell needed yourself and use e.g. `sh` as the command to be called with `add_test()`. I've just run @KağanKayal's example successfully with `add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND sh -c "$<TARGET_FILE:foo> ../test/in.txt > ../test/out.txt")`.

Comment: Yes, explicit call to shell is also an option.