# cmake: make tests successfully passing part of the build process

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to make the passing of tests part of the build process.

Here I use `add_custom_command` to run the test as a `POST_BUILD` step.

```
function(register_test NAME)

    add_test(${NAME} ${NAME})

    # make the test run as part of the build process
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${NAME})

endfunction()
```

The problem with this approach is that **the test is only run when the target is built**:

```
$ make
```

> ```
> [ 50%] Built target lib1
> Linking CXX executable ../../Debug/bin/lib1_test
> Running 1 test case...
> main.cpp(8): fatal error: in "lib1_test": 
>     critical check lib1() == "lib1" has failed [error != lib1]
>
> *** 1 failure is detected in the test module "Master Test Suite"
>
> make[2]: *** [lib1/test/lib1_test] Error 201
> make[1]: *** [lib1/test/CMakeFiles/lib1_test.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

**If the target doesn't need to be built, then the test is not run, and the build passes.**

Here I don't make any changes, just rerun the build process

```
$ make
```

> ```
> [ 50%] Built target lib1
> [100%] Built target lib1_test
> ```

However, if `lib1_test` is actually run, the test fails.

```
$ ./lib1/test/lib1_test
```

> ```
> Running 1 test case...
> main.cpp(8): fatal error: in "lib1_test": 
>     critical check lib1() == "lib1" has failed [error != lib1]
>
> *** 1 failure is detected in the test module "Master Test Suite"
> ```

A better way to do this would be to make a `lib1_test.passed` target which depends on `lib1_test`, runs the tests, and is only created if the tests pass.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried using `add_custom_target` to create a target `lib1_test.passed` which depends on `lib1_test`, and if successful, creates a file `lib1_test.passed`:

```
add_custom_target(${NAME}.passed
    DEPENDS ${NAME}
    COMMAND ${NAME}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${NAME}.passed)
```

There are 2 shortfalls with what I have currently achieved:

- The running of the test is not part of the normal build process.
  That is, `make` will not *"build"* `lib1_test.passed`;
  I have to explicitly state `make lib1_test.passed`
- `make lib1_test.passed` will always execute `lib1_test`, regardless of whether `lib1_test.passed` is newer than `lib1_test1` or not

**Question:**

How can I make the running of tests part of the build, where a failing test will be always rerun?

Comment: Not get your wish, you want run `lib1_test` even if is not changed? It get different input data or what, why it need rerun if it is not changed?

Comment: No - opposite of that - I want `lib1_test` to be run as part of `make`, and if it passes, typing `make` again **won't** run the test. However, if it fails, typing `make` again **must** run the test again.

Comment: Then you just need `add_custom_target` that depend on binary file `lib1_test` and delete this binary(executable) file if fails, why you not try such variant?

Comment: @user1034749 My `add_custom_target` call doesn't automatically get called when I type `make` - how to get it to be run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what I've got so far. The implementation is pretty quick and dirty but nevertheless it works. Please check and tell if it satisfies your needs.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(test)

enable_testing()

set(lib1_SRC lib.c)

add_library(lib1 ${lib1_SRC})

set(test_SRC test.c)

add_executable(libtest ${test_SRC})
target_link_libraries(libtest lib1)

add_test(NAME libtest COMMAND libtest)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT _libtest_completed
  COMMAND ctest -C $<CONFIGURATION> --output-on-failure
  COMMAND cmake -E touch _libtest_completed
  DEPENDS libtest
)

add_custom_target(
  libtest_force ALL
  DEPENDS _libtest_completed
)
```

Source files for the sake of completeness:

lib.c:

```
#include "lib.h"

#include <time.h>

int lib_func() {
    return time(NULL) % 2;
}
```

lib.h:

```
#pragma once

int lib_func();
```

test.c:

```
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    return lib_func();
}
```

Unfortunately it's impossible to depend directly on `test` target due to [CMake bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8438) so we have to perform sunset manually.

Comment: Is there a way to make `libtest_force` be built when building `lib1`? That is, if I type `make lib1` it will build `lib1`, `libtest` and `libtest_force` (thereby running the tests).

Comment: The three are "top targets", so you can use `add_dependencies`. But I would avoid circular dependencies, it brings more problems than solves.

Comment: I have come up with something which more-or-less works. If you would, please take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36702886/955273) to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701286/cmake-replicate-boost-builds-build-everything-in-jamfile-behaviour/36702886) and comment if you have any. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented your solution, thank you very much for your help with this. I have come up with a [slight wrinkle I can't figure out though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105210/cmake-run-test-as-part-of-the-build-process-and-capture-stdout-output-to-file) - namely, capturing the test stdout to a file and only displaying it if there is a test failure. Any insight you may have would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in @user3159253 answer you need an output file (with a time stamp) for the build environment to check if it has to "build" the target in question again. So if your executable was successfully build - even if the subsequent call to run it fails - won't build again.

I wanted to add a solution where you can have only one target. It will rename the test executable output, run it and - if successful - rename it again to its original name to sort of mark it as "passed":

```
function(register_test NAME)

    add_test(NAME ${NAME} COMMAND ${NAME})

    set(TMP "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${NAME}>/tmp_$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${NAME}>")
    set(ORG "$<TARGET_FILE:${NAME}>")

    # make the test run as part of the build process
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${NAME} 
        POST_BUILD 
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename "${ORG}" "${TMP}"
        COMMAND ${TMP}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename "${TMP}" "${ORG}"
    )

endfunction()
```