# cmake: replicate boost-build's "build everything in Jamfile" behaviour?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-build

I am converting a [`boost-build`](http://www.boost.org/build/) build system to cmake.

One of the features of boost-build is that you can specify a path to a `Jamfile` (the equivalent of a `CMakeLists.txt` file) and all the targets specified therein will be built.

For example, with the following project structure:

```
root
|
+--- foo
|    |
|    +--- test
|
+--- bar
|    |
|    +--- test
|
+--- app
```

If you enter the following command:

```
$ b2 foo
```

The `Jamfile` under `root/foo` will be executed, resulting in the `foo` library being built, and the `test` tests being built and run

### boost-build example

Here is a simple build configuration using `boost-build`:

**`Jamroot`:**

```
using gcc ;

project proj : requirements
    <link>static
    <include>.
;

build-project foo ;
```

**`foo/Jamfile`:**

```
lib foo : [ glob *.cpp ] ;

build-project test ;
```

**`foo/test/Jamfile`:**

```
import testing ;

unit-test foo-tests
:   [ glob *.cpp ]
    ..//foo
;
```

You will notice that within `foo's Jamfile` there is a directive `build-project test`

This means that if I type `b2 foo` then everything in `lib/Jamfile` will be executed, resulting in `foo` **and** `foo/test` being built.

Also, within the `Jamroot` there is a directive `build-project foo`

This means that if I just type `b2` then everything in `Jamroot` will be executed, resulting in `foo` and `foo/test` being built.

It is thus easy to build the **whole project** and get **all sources and all tests built.**

It is also easy to build **just a subdirectory** and get **only it's sources and tests build.**

It is this behaviour I'm trying to replicate.

### cmake example

**`root/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(proj CXX)

add_subdirectory(foo)
```

**`foo/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
file(GLOB src "*.cpp")

add_library(foo STATIC ${src})

add_subdirectory(test)
```

**`foo/test/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
file(GLOB src "*.cpp")

add_executable(foo_test ${src})

add_test(foo_test foo_test foo)

# run tests if foo_test.passed is missing or outdated
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  foo_test.passed
    COMMAND foo_test
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch foo_test.passed
    DEPENDS foo_test
    )

# make tests run as part of ALL target
add_custom_target(run_foo_test
    ALL
    DEPENDS foo_test.passed)
```

The above `CMakeLists.txt` structure allows me to `make` and have both  `foo` and `foo_test` built.

However, if I specify `make foo`, **only** `foo` will be built, but `foo_test` won't be, and the tests won't be run.

**Question:**

- How can I have everything within `foo/CMakeLists.txt` built when I type `make foo`?
- Alternately, how can I cause target `foo_test.passed` to be built as part of updating target `foo` **AND** build as part of the `ALL` target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation which achieves the requirements.

It's a bit convoluted as it requires several phony targets and dependency chaining.

**Step 1:**

- create a phony target which all other targets for a "module" will be collected under
- add the phony target to `ALL` so that it is built as part of the global build process

`foo/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# create a phony target which all 'foo' related items will be added to
add_custom_target(foo
    ALL
    )
```

**Step 2:**

- add every target within the "module" as a dependency to this phony target

**`libfoo`:**

- Note here I have renamed `foo` to `libfoo` as we've now used `foo` for our earlier phony target.
- (This will in fact result in the generated library being called `liblibfoo.a`, which is a bit ugly)

`foo/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(libfoo STATIC ${src})

# add libfoo as a dependency of foo, so 'make foo' will build libfoo
add_dependencies(foo 
    libfoo)
```

**`foo_test`:**

Making the tests run automatically as part of the build is a bit convoluted.

You have to:

- create the test executable
- add a `custom_command` which runs the tests and generates a sentinel file (`foo_test.passed`) if they pass
- add a `custom_target` (`foo_test.run`) which depends on the sentinel (`foo_test.passed`)
- add a dependency between `foo` and `foo_test.run`

`foo_test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable       (foo_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_test libfoo ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

# create foo_test.passed command which generates the sentinel file when the tests pass
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  foo_test.passed
    COMMAND foo_test
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch foo_test.passed
    DEPENDS foo_test
    )

# create foo_test.run target which depends on foo_test.passed
add_custom_target(foo_test.run
    DEPENDS foo_test.passed
    )

# add foo_test.run as a dependency of foo, so 'make foo' will build foo_test.run
add_dependencies(foo
    foo_test.run
    )
```

As such, target `foo` has `libfoo` and `foo_test.run` as dependencies.

As a result, both `make` and `make foo` build `libfoo` and build and run `foo_test` (via `foo_test.run` and `foo_test.passed`)

**Perceived clunkiness:**

- The `foo` -> `foo_test.run` -> `foo_test.passed` -> `foo_test` dependency chain.
- In `boost-build` you can name the library `foo` without causing a clash between the `foo` phony target and the `foo` library (and `b2 foo` builds both the `foo` library and its tests)

However, it works, and in the absence of a more elegant solution, will give me what I want.

Comment: Well, first of all, usage of globbing in CMake to collect source files is [discouraged by the authors](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/file.html), see "Note:". Since CMake generates a statical set of make rules for each given source file, creating a new .cpp file without touching `CMakeLists.txt` won't include it into the build process. Likewise, removal of a file from filesystem won't exclude it from the build process. BTW automake has a similar [mis]feature, and they specifically stated why this is a bad practice. Maybe it's inevitably in a two stage build system.