# CMake - run test as part of the build process and capture stdout output to file

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

We have several unit tests which we would like to be run as part of our build process.

To achieve this I have a helper script which creates a custom command that runs the test, and if successful, creates a file `"test_name.passed"`.

I then add a custom target `"test_name.run"` which depends on `"test_name.passed"`.

The idea is that if `"test_name.passed"` doesn't exist or is older than `"test_name"`, the custom command will be run.

Builds will continue to run the custom command until the test passes. Once it passes, subsequent builds won't call the custom command, so the test won't be run when it doesn't need to.

**So far this all works exactly as described**

Here is the script:

```
# create command which runs the test and creates a sentinel file if it passes
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}>
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    DEPENDS ${TEST_NAME}
    )

# create test.run module which depends on test.passed
add_custom_target(${TEST_NAME}.run
    ALL
    DEPENDS ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    )
```

**The problem - noise on `stdout`**

The problem is that our tests often log a tonne of information to `stdout`, and it makes for a very noisy build.

I'm trying to now capture `stdout` to a file, and only in the event of a failure, display the test output.

My first attempt was to try a Bash shell scripting syntax - capture `stdout` into a file and when the exit status is an error, cat the file.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}> > ${TEST_NAME}.output || cat ${TEST_NAME}.output
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    DEPENDS ${TEST_NAME}
    )
```

This doesn't work, as even if the test fails I am getting the sentinal `"test_name.passed"` file created, which means the next time I try to build it thinks the test passed.

**Possible sub-standard fix**

By integrating with `ctest`, I can run each test through ctest and use the command-line option `--output-on-failure`

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    COMMAND ctest --build-config $<CONFIGURATION> --tests-regex ${TEST_NAME} --output-on-failure
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    DEPENDS ${TEST_NAME}
    )
```

The problems with this are two-fold.

1. It *vastly* increases the build time. Each and every test has to be executed through a separate ctest process, all the registered test names parsed against the regex, etc. With the number of individual tests we have the extra time adds up considerably.
2. ctest outputs a lot of noise by default. Specifying the `--quiet` flag suppresses the `--output-on-failure` flag, so you can either have noisy output or no output - there is no way to only get the failures.

**Question**

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

ie:

- Run the test manually (ie: not through ctest)
- Capture the output to a file
- Only output that file in the event of the test exit status indicating failure.
- Touch a sentinel file in the event of the test exit status indicating success.

Bonus points for a cross-platform method, but if it has to be Linux only, then so be it.

Comment: Why not just use ctest and its integration with cmake?

Comment: @user1034749 AFAIK ctest doesn't run tests as part of the build. It's a separate target `make test`. I did previously use ctest to run each test (`COMMAND ctest --build-config $<CONFIGURATION> --tests-regex ${TEST_NAME} --output-on-failure`) but calling through ctest for every unit test vastly increases the build time

Comment: @user1034749 updated my question with what I tried in relation to ctest, and why I am looking for an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I found a solution which works for me.

In the below excerpt, `${ARG_NAME}` is the test binary which we've built and want to run.

There are 2 files created whilst running the tests

- `${ARG_NAME}.output` which contains the test output
- `${ARG_NAME}.passed` which is a sentinel file created if the test is successful

The `custom_command` consists of several commands, and we rely on the fact that cmake will stop executing as soon as one of them fails.

We run the test:

```
${ARG_NAME}
```

All test output is redirected to `${ARG_NAME}.output`, so we don't pollute stdout when the tests pass

```
${ARG_NAME} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1
```

Using the test's exit status, in the event of a failure we cat the file:

```
${ARG_NAME} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1 || cat ${OUTPUT_FILE}
```

However, only when the test passes do we want to create the sentinel file, so we *both* cat the file and run `false`

```
${ARG_NAME} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1 || (cat ${OUTPUT_FILE} && false)
```

If the test passes (exit status is 0), then we won't have run the `cat output && false`, so then the next cmake command is run

```
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PASSED_FILE}
```

Finally we create a `custom_target` which depends on the `.passed` file

```
set(OUTPUT_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${ARG_NAME}.output)
set(PASSED_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${ARG_NAME}.passed)

# create test.passed command which runs this test and creates a sentinel file
# if it passes
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${PASSED_FILE}

    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${ARG_NAME} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1 
              || (cat ${OUTPUT_FILE} && false)

    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PASSED_FILE}

    COMMENT
        "Running ${ARG_NAME} tests"

    DEPENDS
        ${ARG_NAME}

    USES_TERMINAL
    )

# create test.run target which depends on test.passed
add_custom_target(${ARG_NAME}.run
    ALL
    DEPENDS ${PASSED_FILE}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no standard way to redirect output from a command invoked through `add_custom_command` to a file. The CMake command `execute_process` however does have that capability.

Thus a possible solution is to run the test executable from a configured CMake script which itself is run as a CMake custom command. The following code sketches the necessary steps:

In your `CMakeLists.txt` which adds the test, configure a CMake script template:

```
configure_file("test_runner.cmake.in" "test_runner_${TEST_NAME}.cmake" @ONLY)
```

Then add a custom command to invoke the script at build time:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  ${TEST_NAME}.passed
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "test_runner_${TEST_NAME}.cmake" $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}>
    DEPENDS ${TEST_NAME}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

The actual path of the test executable is passed to the script as an argument via a generator expression.

The template test runner script `test_runner.cmake.in` runs the test executable with `execute_process` and redirects error output to a log file:

```
set (_testExecutable "${CMAKE_ARGV3}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_testExecutable} ERROR_FILE "@TEST_NAME@.output" RESULT_VARIABLE _testResult)
if (_testResult)
    file(REMOVE "@TEST_NAME@.passed")
    file(READ "@TEST_NAME@.output" _contents)
    message (STATUS "${_contents}")
else()
    file(WRITE "@TEST_NAME@.passed" "")
endif()
```

If the test fails, the script removes the sentinel file and outputs the error log.
If the test succeeds, the script creates the sentinel file.