# CMake and add test program command

Tags: makefile, cmake

I use usually makefile for project but I want to start learn CMake.
I use makefile not only for build my project but also to test my project.
It's very useful.
How can I do that with CMake?

For exemple this makefile:

```
pathword=words.txt
flags=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -Og
#flags=-std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -s

default: TextMiningCompiler TextMiningApp

TextMiningCompiler: TextMiningCompiler.cpp trie.cpp
    g++ $(flags) TextMiningCompiler.cpp trie.cpp -o TextMiningCompiler

TextMiningApp: TextMiningApp.cpp
    g++ $(flags) TextMiningApp.cpp -o TextMiningApp

run: TextMiningCompiler TextMiningApp
    ./TextMiningCompiler $(pathword) totoro.txt
    cat test.txt | time ./TextMiningApp totoro.txt

clean:
    trash TextMiningCompiler TextMiningApp
```

I made this CMakefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (TextMining)
add_executable(TextMiningApp TextMiningApp.cpp)
add_executable(TextMiningCompiler TextMiningCompiler.cpp trie.cpp read_words_file.cpp)
set_property(TARGET TextMiningApp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET TextMiningCompiler PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

How can I have the make run function? or other custom function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_custom_target.html)

> Adds a target with the given name that executes the given commands.

Usage is straightforward:

```
add_custom_target(run
     COMMAND ./TextMiningCompiler <pathword> totoro.txt
     COMMAND cat test.txt | time ./TextMiningApp totoro.txt
)
add_dependencies(run TextMiningCompiler TextMiningApp)
```

Comment: Maybe just copy/paste, but shouldn't that be `add_custom_target()` instead of `add_custom_command()` in the example code snippet also?

Comment: @Florian: Yes, it should be `add_custom_target`, thanks for point.

Answer (score 24):

When it gets to tests in CMake I prefer to use [`add_test()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html). It enables - besides calling something like `make test` to run the tests - the possibility to e.g. get test reports via [ctest](/questions/tagged/ctest) (distributed with CMake).

Using the name of an executable's CMake target as "command" in `add_test()` directly replaces it with the excutable's path:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (TextMining)

enable_testing()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(pathword "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/words.txt")

add_executable(TextMiningCompiler TextMiningCompiler.cpp trie.cpp read_words_file.cpp)
add_test(
    NAME TestTextMiningCompiler 
    COMMAND TextMiningCompiler "${pathword}" "totoro.txt"
)

add_executable(TextMiningApp TextMiningApp.cpp)
add_test(
    NAME TestTextMiningApp 
    COMMAND sh -c "cat ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test.txt | time $<TARGET_FILE:TextMiningApp> totoro.txt"
)
set_tests_properties(TestTextMiningApp PROPERTIES DEPENDS TestTextMiningCompiler)
```

---

You could further eliminate the dependency to a shell like `sh` if you would add a commandline parameter to `TextMiningApp` to pass `test.txt` as input:

```perl
add_test(
    NAME TestTextMiningApp 
    COMMAND TextMiningApp -i "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test.txt" "totoro.txt"
)
```

---

And no need to add a `time` call since total time of execution is automatically measured when executing the test via `make test` (which is btw. equivalent to calling [`ctest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html)):

```
$ make test
Running tests...
Test project [... path to project's binary dir ...]
    Start 1: TestTextMiningCompiler
1/2 Test #1: TestTextMiningCompiler ...........   Passed    0.11 sec
    Start 2: TestTextMiningApp
2/2 Test #2: TestTextMiningApp ................   Passed    0.05 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.19 sec
```

**Reference**

- [How to use redirection in cmake add_test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304289/how-to-use-redirection-in-cmake-add-test)