# CMake does not find custom command "ls"

Tags: windows, cmake

I try to run some basic commands for my CLion projects, but it just doesn't work. Here is my CMake setting.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(hello)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(hello ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_custom_command(OUTPUT hello.out
        COMMAND ls -l hello
        DEPENDS hello)

add_custom_target(run_hello_out
        DEPENDS hello.out)
```

I got the following error messages when running run_hello_out in CLion.

```
[100%] Generating hello.out
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ls -l hello, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [hello.out] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_hello_out.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_hello_out.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [run_hello_out] Error 2
CMakeFiles\run_hello_out.dir\build.make:59: recipe for target 'hello.out' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/run_hello_out.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:73: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/run_hello_out.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'run_hello_out' failed
```

It is supposed to run "ls -l hello" and see the results in either build window or run window.

Comment: The CMake code in question is not what is being used during build. I presume you have `COMMAND "ls -l hello"` (command + arguments quoted) instead. Another guess is that maybe you're running the command on Windows and there's no "ls" executable in your %PATH%.

Comment: Thank you. It is in my %path%, but it doesn't work for CMake. So I tried full path instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow `ls` doesn't work even I set up the global path correctly. CMake needs full path. The following works and solves the issue.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hello.out
        COMMAND "C:\\FULL PATH HERE\\ls" -l hello
        DEPENDS hello)
```

Answer (score 3):

**The Problem**

CMake doesn't guaranty a shell context for its `COMMAND` calls and it doesn't automatically search for the executable given with `COMMAND` itself.

It mainly puts the given command into the generated build environment and depends on how it's handled there.

In your case I assume you/CLion is running `cmake` and `mingw32-make` in a MS Windows `cmd` shell. In this case you would have had to use the `dir` instead of the `ls` command:

```
add_custom_target(
    run_hello_out
    COMMAND dir $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:hello>
    DEPENDS hello
)
```

**Possible Soltions**

I see three possible solutions. Either

1. Provide a `bash` shell context

   ```
   include(FindUnixCommands)

   if (BASH)
       add_custom_target(
           run_hello_out
           COMMAND ${BASH} -c "ls -l hello"
           DEPENDS hello
       )
   endif()
   ```
2. Use CMake's shell abstraction [`cmake -E`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) (only limited number of commands, e.g. no `ls` equivalent)

   ```
   add_custom_target(
       run_hello_out
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<TARGET_FILE:hello>
       DEPENDS hello
   )
   ```
3. Search for the executable with [`find_program()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html).

   ```
   find_program(LS ls)

   if (LS)
       add_custom_target(
           run_hello_out
           COMMAND ${LS} -l hello
           DEPENDS hello
   endif()
   ```

**Reference**

- [How to use redirection in cmake add_test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304289/how-to-use-redirection-in-cmake-add-test)