# Is it possible to find all the executables with the same name?

Tags: r, cmake

**What I'm doing** I'm writing a *CMakeLists.txt* to build a C++ project that will need to use *R*.

**what is my problem** Usually, when I would like to find a package/program, I would use `find_package/program` function. But this only finds the first one in the path. What if I want to find all the executables with the same name?

For example, if somebody has multiple versions of R installed on the computer, can I find them all and return a list? An alternative can be that is there a way to detect if there are multiple R executables installed?

Thank you!

Comment: @BenBolker From the [tag:cmake] tag and the commands shown it seems this is about a cross-platform way of finding all programs with the same name in CMake.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, voted for reopen.

Comment: @Tsyvarev How do I close this question? I already have the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @WeimingHu: Questions are *closed* only when they have **inappropriate content** for the site, see [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for more info. As for your question, simply having an answer doesn't imply that it should be closed. They said, Stack Overflow is **Question/Answer** (Q/A) site, that is having answered questions is the main purpose of it. If you find an answer fitting for your purpose, you may mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev has answered there is not build-in way in [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake), but you can always do this within a loop.

So here is my cross-platform version of the missing `find_program_all()` CMake function:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(TestFindProgramAll NONE)

function(find_program_all _var)
    if (NOT DEFINED ${_var})
        while(1)
            unset(_found CACHE)
            find_program(_found ${ARGN})
            if (_found AND NOT _found IN_LIST ${_var})
                set(${_var} "${${_var}};${_found}" CACHE FILEPATH "Path to a program." FORCE)
                # ignore with the next try
                get_filename_component(_dir "${_found}" DIRECTORY)
                list(APPEND CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH "${_dir}")
            else()
                unset(_found CACHE)
                break()
            endif()
        endwhile()
    endif()
endfunction()

find_program_all(_gcc "gcc")
message(STATUS "_gcc = ${_gcc}")
```

It mimics the [`find_program()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) behavior and caches the result.

Tested it with my multiple `gcc` installations.

**References**

- [`CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH.html)
- [Environment variable used by CMake to detect Visual C++ compiler tools for Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069632/environment-variable-used-by-cmake-to-detect-visual-c-compiler-tools-for-ninja)

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you for sharing. I will test this solution.

Answer (score 1):

CMake has no *ready-to-use* functionality to return **list** of matched programs.

You may iterate over search paths manually, or use other utilities, like `which -a` suggested by @BenBolker in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747896/is-it-possible-to-find-all-the-executables-with-the-same-name#comment76477142_44747896).